# How to replace link to specific file type in wordpress database in meta_value?

Tags: sql, wordpress, replace, hyperlink

I was trying to replace my video link in my wordpress site to another subdomain, I have got a small issue with attached video files.

Under meta_value:

```
old link: https://example.com/wp-content/uplaods/2022/09/file.mp4

new link: https://newlink.com/my_files/myvids/2022/09/file.mp4
```

When I run this code:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'old_url.com','new_url.com');
```

But the problem is that meta_key is same for images and videos: meta_key is: **_wp_attached_file**

So when I change the link it affects image link as well, however I just want to change the links that contain only mp4 files in meta_value and meta_key with _wp_attached_file . so is there any way to just change the link that contain video files such as .mp4 for example?

Appreciate that.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have t6o add a WHERE clause to your Update so that only the values for example with ening mp4 will be updated

> ```
> CREATE tABLe wp_postmeta (meta_value varchar(100))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO wp_postmeta VALUEs ('https://example.com/wp-content/uplaods/2022/09/file.mp4')
> ,('https://example.com/wp-content/uplaods/2022/09/file.jpg'),('https://example.com/wp-content/uplaods/2022/09/file.png')
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'example.com','examplenew.com')
> WHERE meta_value LIKE '%.mp4'
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta
> ```
>
> ```
> meta_value
> https:\/\/examplenew.com\/wp-content\/uplaods\/2022\/09\/file.mp4
> https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/uplaods\/2022\/09\/file.jpg
> https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/uplaods\/2022\/09\/file.png
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3cd3027b9c738ca5c8181c3e51f8f7b3)*

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to solve it by adding `where meta_value like '%mp4'`.